# Fedora 15 - Audio Configuration

Tags: linux, fedora, audio, configuration, pulseaudio

I have a Macbook Pro 6,1 that I have dual booting OSX and now Fedora 15. I'm working on getting the audio working.

In System Settings > Sound > Output there are two options for audio devices:

```
High Definition Audio Control Digital Stereo (HDMI)
Internal Audio Analog Stereo
```

There is no sound when the first option (HD Audio Control Digital Stereo) is selected. However, if the second (Internal Audio Analog Stereo) is selected the headphone jack works, but the on board speakers do not work.

I can't even tell what actual hardware on the laptop is. The Apple website (http://support.apple.com/kb/SP621) just says,

> Stereo speakers with subwoofers, omnidirectional microphone, audio line in minijack (digital/analog), audio line out/headphone minijack (digital/analog)

How do I get the speakers working?

Comment: I think the audio device is PCI, try `lspci`. A classic problem is having one of the volume controls set to mute and a mixer application that doesn't display all controls; try all the mixers you can find and try fiddling with all the volume settings.

Comment: Some of the mixers to try are alsamixer (try pressing F6 to select audio cards), kmix if you have KDE and pavucontrol if you are using PulseAudio.

Comment: The first, by the way, is for passing sound the HDMI output cable.  IE, when you connect the computer to a TV via an HDMI cable you can have the sound go to the TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working. Problem was the channels were muted. See instructions here: http://linsek.com/?q=node/12